# How to design to store Price of product variant assuming product variant could have different price?

Tags: database-design, data-modeling

I have Product table ,

```
 product
 ----------------
 id   name
 1    Puma T-shirt

 variant
  ----------------
  id name
  1  Size
  2  Colour
  3  Brand
  4  Fabric


 options
  ----------------
  id name
  1  Small
  2  Medium
  3  Large
  4  Puma
  5  Adidas
  6  Red
  7  Green
  8  cotton


 product_variant
 -----------------
  id  product_id variant_id
   1    1         1          (Puma T-shirt, Size)
   2    1         2          (Puma T-shirt, Colour)
   3    1         3          (Puma T-shirt, Brand)
   4    1         4          (Puma T-shirt, Fabric)


product_variant_options
------------------------
 id    product_variant_option_id   option_id
  1          1                         1       (Puma T-shirt Size) , (Small)
  2          2                         6       (Puma T-shirt Colour), (Red)
```

Just Wanted to know how to store price for each variant, because different variant could have different price

I tried product variant design but I'm blocked to design its price architecture